# Compile-time Check on Sum of Nat's?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I attempted to write a typeclass, `SumEq5`, such that its `HList` type parameter's first two fields add up to `5`:

```
trait SumEq5[A]
object SumEq5 {
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit ev: SumEq5[L]): SumEq5[L] = ev

  implicit def sumEq5Ev[L <: HList, A <: Nat, B <: Nat](
    implicit hcons: IsHCons.Aux[L, A, B :: HNil],
             ev: Sum.Aux[A, B, _5]
  ): SumEq5[L] = new SumEq5[L] {}
}
```

But it doesn't appear to work:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.nat._
import net.SumEq5

scala> SumEq5[_0 :: _5 :: HNil]
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for 
    parameter ev: net.SumEq5[shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._0,shapeless.::
       [shapeless.nat._5,shapeless.HNil]]]
       SumEq5[_0 :: _5 :: HNil]
```

Please give me a hint as to why `_0 :: _5 :: HNil` does not have evidence that its two `Nat`'s are equal to 5.

**EDIT**

Updated question per Denis Rosca's help in [shapeless's gitter](https://gitter.im/milessabin/shapeless?at=58949d1b2ff29dec067215fa).

Comment: The trait is empty, so why not just `new SumEq5[L]` ?

Comment: That's fine, but it will won't work for my input, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dale Wijnand and Marcus Henry are pointing in the right direction if you want to generalize to `HList`s of arbitrary length, however if you really only want to accommodate two element `HList`s, then the following is a rather simpler solution,

```
scala> import shapeless._, nat._, ops.nat._
import shapeless._
import nat._
import ops.nat._

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait SumEq5[A]

object SumEq5 {
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit ev: SumEq5[L]): SumEq5[L] = ev

  implicit def sumEq5AB[A <: Nat, B <: Nat]
    (implicit ev: Sum.Aux[A, B, _5]): SumEq5[A :: B :: HNil] =
      new SumEq5[A :: B :: HNil] {}
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait SumEq5
defined object SumEq5

scala> SumEq5[_0 :: _5 :: HNil]
res0: SumEq5[_0 :: _5 :: HNil]] = SumEq5$$anon$1@658c5e59
```

The main difference here is that the instance is explicitly defined for two element lists rather than being defined for lists in general with the proviso that there exists a proof that the list has exactly two elements.

Following Dale's update, we can generalize this to accommodate `HList`s with at least two (rather than exactly two) elements, again without any additional witnesses,

```
scala> import shapeless._, nat._, ops.nat._
import shapeless._
import nat._
import ops.nat._

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait SumEq5[A]

object SumEq5 {
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit ev: SumEq5[L]): SumEq5[L] = ev

  implicit def sumEq5AB[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, T <: HList]
    (implicit ev: Sum.Aux[A, B, _5]): SumEq5[A :: B :: T] =
      new SumEq5[A :: B :: T] {}
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait SumEq5
defined object SumEq5

scala> SumEq5[_0 :: _5 :: HNil]
res0: SumEq5[_0 :: _5 :: HNil]] = SumEq5$$anon$1@658c5e59
```

Comment: Indeed, much simpler. I would assume, though, that the idea was the handle any HList of 2 or more elements, of which the sum of the first two is 5.

Comment: Updated to capture that case too.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. Kevin, here's your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I only have a partial answer for you, i.e. a (workaround) solution without understanding why exactly the original doesn't work as intended.

Seems you can't ask directly for a `IsHCons.Aux[L, A, B :: HNil]`, you need to do it piecemeal:

1. `IsHCons.Aux[L, A, L2]`, and then
2. `IsHCons.Aux[L2, B, HNil]`

Therefore, this compiles:

```
import shapeless._, nat._, ops.hlist._, ops.nat._

trait SumEq5[A]
object SumEq5 {
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit ev: SumEq5[L]): SumEq5[L] = ev

  implicit def sumEq5Ev[L <: HList, L2 <: HList, A <: Nat, B <: Nat](
    implicit hcons0: IsHCons.Aux[L, A, L2],
             hcons: IsHCons.Aux[L2, B, HNil],
             ev: Sum.Aux[A, B, _5]
  ): SumEq5[L] = new SumEq5[L] {}
}

object T {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SumEq5[_0 :: _5 :: HNil]
  }
}
```

---

Following from [Miles Sabin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42066705/463761), this can be tweaked to support any HList of 2 or more elements, of which the sum of the first two is 5, like so:

```
import shapeless._, nat._, ops.hlist._, ops.nat._

trait SumEq5[A]
object SumEq5 {
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit ev: SumEq5[L]): SumEq5[L] = ev

  implicit def sumEq5Ev[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, L3 <: HList, A <: Nat, B <: Nat](
    implicit hcons1: IsHCons.Aux[L1, A, L2],
             hcons2: IsHCons.Aux[L2, B, L3],
             ev: Sum.Aux[A, B, _5]
  ): SumEq5[L1] = new SumEq5[L1] {}
}

object T {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SumEq5[_0 :: _5 :: HNil]
  }
}
```

Comment: I see this a lot when people first learn to work wirh recursive or inductive types. The compiler needs to go step wise. Kevin, is trying to get an instance for A::B::HNil without first having an instance for B::HNil without first having an instance for HNil. The solution here sidesteps the need for an inductive process by adding one more IsHCons layer. To do it inductively you'd need to prove B::HNil is less than or equal _5, then A::B::HNil is equal _5 in two implicit defs.

Comment: Thanks, Dale and Marcus! This answer and comment definitely helped me learn more.